# Building a Yocto bitbake recipe, which depends on grpc, grpc-native fails saying the the grpc_cpp_plugin does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, cross-compiling, yocto

I am developing a C++ component that uses gRPC and use the following definitions in my bitbase recipe (Yocto `dunfell`) to build it with CMake:

```
DEPENDS += "\
    grpc \
    grpc-native \
    ...
    "

inherit cmake pkgconfig
```

I included `grpc-native` to be able to use the `protoc` compiler to generate stubs and `grpc` to link my component with the gRPC libraries for the target host.

In my CMakeLists.txt I use the following CMake functions to find the libraries/cpp-plugin

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_program(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN grpc_cpp_plugin REQUIRED)
```

However, building the recipe fails with the following error:

```
| CMake Error at /home/jayjay/build-master/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-mbient-linux/mycomponent/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake:197 (message):
|   The imported target "gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin" references the file
|
|      "/home/jayjay/build-master/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-mbient-linux/mycomponent/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin"
|
|   but this file does not exist.
```

And it is true, the `grpc_cpp_plugin` does not exist in this directory, as well as all the other plugins like `grpc_node_plugin`, `grpc_php_plugin`, etc. However, these plugins exist in the corresponding "recipe-sysroot`-native`/usr/bin/" directory, which is correct as they must be compiled for the build-host (rather than the target host), so that they can be used with `protoc` to generate stubs.

What I do not understand is, that why the existence of these plugin files are checked, although they are not created?

If I remove `grpc` from `DEPENDS` then everything works fine, unless the build host architecture is different from the target host architecture (i.e. for cross compiling). In this case I get a linker error "file in wrong format", which is OK, as I used the libraries compiled for the build host (grpc-native) and not the target host.

As a workaround I simply create all required plugin files in the desired directory like so:

```
do_configure_prepend() {
  touch ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_cpp_plugin
  touch ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_csharp_plugin
  touch ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_node_plugin
  ...
}
```

This works, as only the existence of the files is checked. They are not used.

To be able to find the correct location of the directory with the "native" plugins I pass the following extra parameter to CMake:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "\
    -DSTAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE=${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE} \
    "
```

Needless to say that this does not feel right.

I do not really grasp what am I doing wrong here (sorry for the long explanation)?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you do inside your CMake files with STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE? I have the same issue on Yocto version Gatesgarth.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple: use kirkstone

On dunfell, the gRPC recipe does not include https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/31525 which I believe fixes the build on Yocto.
So technically you could also just update/patch/make your own gRPC recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for Yocto Gatesgarth and gRPC version 1.24.x.

Basically I symlink the plugin binaries from recipe-sysroot-native/ to recipe-sysroot/ to make the CMake file happy.

Excerpt from my recipe file for a custom software project with CMake and grpc:

```
DEPENDS += "grpc"
DEPENDS += "grpc-native"

do_configure_prepend() {
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_cpp_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_cpp_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_csharp_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_csharp_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_node_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_node_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_objective_c_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_objective_c_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_python_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_python_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_ruby_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_ruby_plugin
    ln -f -s ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/grpc_php_plugin ${STAGING_BINDIR}/grpc_php_plugin
}
```

Note that PROBABLY this will no longer work on later gRPC versions, as they seem to have fixed a lot of things regarding cross compilation in gRPC with version 1.35 and above (see oe-core changelog for grpc_*.bb).

Thanks goes out to all these sources!

[Yocto Lists](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/83045841?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,300,83045841#)

[Another Yocto Mailinglist](https://yhbt.net/lore/all/b50e6ff8-5fb9-e654-f895-7e6a494f564b@gmail.com/t/)

[gRPC Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17708)

[gRPC Pull request with one solution](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/31525)

[gRPC Pull request with another solution](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/22498)

---

Edit:
Since I am now on Yocto Honister with gRPC 1.38.1 the situation has changed as follows:

The above workaround is still needed to cross compile a cmake grpc project from within yocto.

However, on the SDK the grpc_cpp_plugin is no longer included in the SDK, thus I cannot cross compile with the SDK outside of yocto. Here is my workaround:

grpc_1.38.1.bbappend

```
# We need grpc_cpp_plugin and shared libraries enabled
IMAGE_FEATURES += "cpp shared"

# grpc_cpp_plugin native binary is not correctly installed in this version.
# force it to be included in the yocto sdk
FILES:${PN}-native += " ${bindir}"
FILES:${PN}-nativesdk += " ${bindir}"
FILES:${PN}-compiler += " \
    ${bindir} \
    ${libdir}/libgrpc_plugin_support${SOLIBS} \
"
IMAGE_FEATURES += "cpp shared"
```

And inside my image or local.conf:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "\
    grpc-compiler \
"
```

I am still looking forward to the day I can switch to Yocto Kirkstone ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The response from Martin is very helpful. I found overriding the PACKAGECONFIG variable when using grpc_1.38.1 with a bbappend did the job too (instead of using IMAGE_FEATURES).  You can also add the csharp and python plugins if you make a grpc_%.bbappend file with the following added;

```
PACKAGECONFIG = "cpp shared csharp python"
```

Another tweak that appeared to matter was to request the grpc-compiler on the target or host toolchain with the following code added to your image recipe;

```
# Add grpc-compiler to target tools
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "\
    grpc-compiler \
"

# Add grpc-compiler (and protoc) to host toolchain
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "\
    nativesdk-protobuf \
    nativesdk-protobuf-dev \
    nativesdk-grpc \
    nativesdk-grpc-compiler \
"
```