# How to write a bitbake recipe for a gRPC example using cmake

Tags: cmake, grpc, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to get the gRPC helloworld example to be compiled with a bitbake recipe. The objective being able to call the greeter-client/server from the embedded target.
But, when I do a `bitbake grpc-helloworld`, I get the following error message:

> -- Using protobuf 3.11.4
> -- Found ZLIB: /home/buildbot/oe-core/build/tmp/work/aarch64-tdx-linux/grpc-helloworld/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libz.so
> (found version "1.2.11")
> -- Found OpenSSL: /home/buildbot/oe-core/build/tmp/work/aarch64-tdx-linux/grpc-helloworld/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypto.so
> (found version "1.1.1o") CMake Error at
> recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake:197 (message):
> The imported target "gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin" references the file
> "/home/buildbot/oe-core/build/tmp/work/aarch64-tdx-linux/grpc-helloworld/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin"
>
> but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:   * The
> file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.   * An
> install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.   * The
> installation package was faulty and contained "/home/buildbot/oe-core/build/tmp/work/aarch64-tdx-linux/grpc-helloworld/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake"
> but not all the files it references.
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake:16 (include)
> common.cmake:116 (find_package)   CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The grpc_cpp_plugin is indeed not in recipe-sysroot. How do I fix that?

File structure for the recipe:

```
recipes-customer/
  grpc-helloworld_1.0.0.bb
  grpc-helloworld/
    CMakeLists.txt
    common.cmake
    greeter_client.cc
    greeter_server.cc
    helloworld.proto
```

Other than for the proto file and common.cmake paths, the CMakeLists.txt is the same as in the grpc example (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt).

I just changed the common.cmake for finding Protobuf from `find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)` to `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)`, otherwise this error appeared:

> CMake Error at common.cmake:103 (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any   of the
> following names:
>
> ProtobufConfig.cmake
> protobuf-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
> set   "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
> If   "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
> sure it has   been installed. Call Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)

This is the bitbake recipe so far, grpc-helloworld_1.0.0.bb:

```
SUMMARY = "gRPC Hello World"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
DEPENDS += "protobuf grpc"
SRC_URI += "file://CMakeLists.txt file://*.cc file://*.h"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

Why do these errors happen?
Thank you for your help.

Edit: This same problem was unanswered here ([Building a Yocto bitbake recipe, which depends on grpc, grpc-native fails saying the the grpc_cpp_plugin does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809320/building-a-yocto-bitbake-recipe-which-depends-on-grpc-grpc-native-fails-saying))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is actually very simple: do not use dunfell.

Using kirkstone, what I showed just works (except `file://*` aka glob which are not supported by kirkstone and the fact that the CMakeLists.txt file from the gRPC examples needs a `install(TARGETS greeter_client greeter_server DESTINATION bin)` to complete the recipe task).

I had to be on dunfell until my BSP was updated so I was stuck on this for a while ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling the recipe as above but getting some error. Do you know if anything is missing? I am using kirkstone version to compile the recipe.

```
**ERROR:**
| cd /local/mnt/workspace/vpuar/25_06_qrb5165/build-qti-distro-fullstack-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0/build && _PROTOBUF_PROTOC-NOTFOUND --grpc_out /local/mnt/workspace/vpuar/25_06_qrb5165/build-qti-distro-fullstack-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0/build --cpp_out /local/mnt/workspace/vpuar/25_06_qrb5165/build-qti-distro-fullstack-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0/build -I /local/mnt/workspace/vpuar/25_06_qrb5165/build-qti-distro-fullstack-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0 --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND" /local/mnt/workspace/vpuar/25_06_qrb5165/build-qti-distro-fullstack-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0/helloworld.proto
| /bin/sh: _PROTOBUF_PROTOC-NOTFOUND: command not found
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Inside my files folder, I've all these files:

```
CMakeLists.txt  
common.cmake  
greeter_client.cc  
greeter_server.cc  
helloworld.proto
```

And I've update the files inside CMakeLists.txt file. And the recipe (.bb file) is same as mentioned in the post (grpc-helloworld_1.0.0.bb).

Comment: I am not 100% sure I can help you as we moved away from Yocto for our project. I still have some remnants and I see that my grpc-helloworld_1.0.0.bb is now:
```
SUMMARY = "gRPC Hello World"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILE_CHKSUM = ""
DEPENDS = "protobuf protobuf-c protobuf-native grpc grpc-native"
SRC_URI += "file://common.cmake \
   file://CMakeLists.txt \
   file://greeter_client.cc \
   file://greeter_server.cc \
   file://helloworld.proto \
"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
inherit pkgconfig cmake
```
The change is in the DEPENDS which now has protobuf-c, which I believe contains protoc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your recommendation but I guess there are many changes with the upgrade in grpc recipe and maybe it requires more dependencies to be added. Not sure of it. With your change, I got new error as: "../aarch64-oe-linux/newgrpc/1.0-r0/helloworld.proto | _GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND: program not found or is not executable | Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable| --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1. | ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. "